# Create as factor of true/false based on a vector of 0/1

Tags: r

```
target <- c(1,0,1,0,1,1)
target %>% as.factor(levels = c("false", "true"))
Error in as.factor(., levels = c("false", "true")) : 
  unused argument (levels = c("false", "true"))
```

How can I turn vector target into a factor where 1 corresponds to true and 0 corresponds to false?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
target <- c(1,0,1,0,1,1)
factor(target == 1)
# [1] TRUE  FALSE TRUE  FALSE TRUE  TRUE 
# Levels: FALSE TRUE
```

another way:

```
factor( target, levels = c(0, 1), labels = c(FALSE, TRUE) )
# [1] TRUE  FALSE TRUE  FALSE TRUE  TRUE 
# Levels: FALSE TRUE
```

Coercing numeric to logical type:

```
factor(as.logical(target))
# [1] TRUE  FALSE TRUE  FALSE TRUE  TRUE 
# Levels: FALSE TRUE
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another twist on the same... just rename `levels(target)`. Here's your data as a factor:

```
> target <- as.factor(c(1,0,1,0,1,1))
> levels(target)
[1] "0" "1"
```

Make sure you get them in the same order as the original `levels(target)`:

```
> levels(target) <- c("FALSE","TRUE")
> target
[1] TRUE  FALSE TRUE  FALSE TRUE  TRUE 
Levels: FALSE TRUE
```